# How to update an array/repeated column in bigquery using update statement?

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

Here is my table named, ott_details.

```
id  |  platforms  |  country
101    Netflix       UK
       Prime         US
       peacock       US
```

platforms is a repeated field. So is the country column.

I need to replace the peacock with hotstar using update statement
like below

```
id  |  platforms  |  country
101    Netflix       UK
       Prime         US
       hotstar       US
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
update ott_details t
set platforms = array(
  select if(platform = 'peacock', 'hotstar', platform)
  from t.platforms as platform
)
where 'peacock' in unnest(platforms);
```

if applied to sample data in your question  - result is

[image]

or you can use just

```
update ott_details t
set platforms = array(
  select if(platform = 'peacock', 'hotstar', platform)
  from t.platforms as platform
)
where true;
```

or

```
update ott_details
set platforms = array(
  select if(platform = 'peacock', 'hotstar', platform)
  from unnest(platforms) as platform
)
where true;
```

with same result

pick whatever yon will like more :o)